# jQuery onExists?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does something like this already exist in jQuery?

```
function onExists(o, f) {
  if (o.length) {
    f(o); 
  }
}

onExists($(":button"), function(o) { o.button(); });
```

Comment: I don't think it does, although  `.live()` comes close. What do you need this for?

Comment: The better question is, what do you want to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  `onExists` suggests you want a event when an element is added to the DOM.  Is that what you want?  Your code seems to just check in an element exists.  If you just want to see if an element exists, then `$(":button").length` is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, glad mblase75 asked the question.  I haven't done jQuery in a few months and was thinking that `$(":button").button()` would throw an exception (on there being no .button() on null) if no button existed.  It appears I was wrong.

Comment: @Bradford Right -- if there is no `$(':button')`, then `.length` will be zero, but more importantly any methods you try to execute on `$(':button')` will silently fail because the jQuery object will be empty. So it's pretty rare that you need to test for `.length` in the first place.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always check its existence with length.
like,

```
if($(':button').length > 0) {
    o.button();
}
```